# flat_map in ruby when working with different elements

Tags: ruby

I think flat_map is great when you have an array of hashes of variable lengths and you want to work with each one individually:

```
data = [
  {'apple' => 'fruit'},
  {'carrot' => 'vegetable'},
  {'orange' => 'fruit', 'pear' => 'fruit'},
  {'lettuce' => 'vegetable'}
] 

data.flat_map(&:to_a).reduce([]) {|acc, (k,v)| acc << Hash[k,v] }
 => [{"apple"=>"fruit"}, {"carrot"=>"vegetable"}, {"orange"=>"fruit"}, {"pear"=>"fruit"}, {"lettuce"=>"vegetable"}]
```

But I don't think I fully understand flat_map. According to [docs](http://www.apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map):

> Returns a new array with the concatenated results of running block
>   once for every element in enum.

But look at this example:

```
[[1], {a: "a"}, {b: "b"}].flat_map(&:to_a)
=> [1, [:a, "a"], [:b, "b"]]
```

The first item is stripped from the inner array, the other items are converted to arrays. How does it know to do this?

When I call to_a like this:

```
[1].to_a
 => [1] 
[1].to_a.flatten
 => [1]
```

You see the result is different than what flat_map did. What is flat_map doing in the first example to strip the item of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any array `arr` having `m+n` elements, if

```
arr.map { ... }
```

returns

```
[a1, a2,.., am, o1, o2,.., on]
```

where `a1, a2,.., am` are arrays and `o1, o2,.., on` are objects other than arrays, then by changing `map` to `flat_map`, leaving the block unchanged, `flat_map` will return

```
[*a1, *a2,.., *am, o1, o2,.., on]
```

**Example 1**

For

```
arr = [[1], {a: "a"}, {b: "b"}]
```

we have

```
arr.map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[1], [[:a, "a"]], [[:b, "b"]]]
```

so it follows that

```
arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
```

will return

```
[*[1], *[[:a, "a"]], *[[:b, "b"]]]
  #=> [1, [:a, "a"], [:b, "b"]]
```

and indeed it does.

**Example 2**

Suppose now that we have

```
arr = [1, 'cat', [2,3], {a: 4}]
```

then

```
arr.map(&:itself)
  #=> [1, "cat", [2, 3], {:a=>4}]
```

so

```
arr.flat_map(&:itself)
```

is found to return

```
[1, "cat", 2, 3, {:a=>4}]
```

which is the reduction of

```
[1, "cat", *[2, 3], {:a=>4}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`[1].flatten` is `[1]` - there is no second level. `[[1]].flatten` is `[1]`. This is the difference between your last example and all others.

If you try plain `map` first,

```
[[1], {a: "a"}, {b: "b"}].map(&:to_a)
# => [[1], [[:a, "a"]], [[:b, "b"]]]
```

Notice that each hash arrayifies to an array of arrays (each of which is a pair of a key and a value). When you `flatten` it by one level:

```
[[1], {a: "a"}, {b: "b"}].map(&:to_a).flatten(1)
# => [1, [:a, "a"], [:b, "b"]]
```

This is exactly what you are getting with `flat_map`.